# Grouping multiple objects

Tags: after-effects

I'm using After Effects cc2017 and I am wondering if it is possible to group two or more objects in order to align them to the composition? I have two graphics I wish to center. You can do this in other Adobe software applications such as Illustrator by going to the **object** menu and selecting group**.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes- you can connect objects together using something called parenting. 
There’s a tutorial here

https://www.surfacedstudio.com/tutorials/adobe-effects-basics-tutorial-parenting

You could also pre-comp the objects together.

https://greyscalegorilla.com/tutorials/fun-with-precomping-in-after-effects/

Parenting is like one object controlling another (or one object controlling many other objects). Precomping is more like making a new video and placing your objects inside it (sometimes called nesting in video editors).